# PHPUnit - Class '/path/to/my/class.php' could not be found in ''

Tags: php, php-7.2, phpunit

I have set up PHPUnit on Windows to do unit testing within my Moodle application. My php version is 7.2.10 and the version of PHPUnit is 7.5.

I was able to successfully install composer and then PEAR and PHPUnit.

I was then able to initialise the Moodle PHPUnit test environment by running:

```
php ../phpunit/cli/init.php
```

This successfully set up the test environment and ran all of the unit tests in the application.

The problem I have is when I attempt to run a single test, using e.g.

```
vendor\bin\phpunit /mod/quiz/tests/event_test.php
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Class '/mod/quiz/tests/event_test.php' could not be found in ''.
```

The solution to a similar looking problem, [PHPUnit error - Class could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996734/phpunit-error-class-could-not-be-found), does not solve the issue. I had to modify the solution since the `StandardTestSuiteLoader` class has changed - I tried making all comparisons to `realpath($suiteClassFile)` case insensitive but this has not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with running phpunit against a file path as opposed to a class name, but is this expecting an absolute path?

```
/mod/quiz/tests/event_test.php
```

Is probably trying to be loaded from the root directory.  Either try dropping the leading /, or supply the full windows file path, including C: